# Finding a formula for $[(1+f(t))^{b}]^{(k)}$ with $b$ constant.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find a formula for the kth derived from the function $(1 + f(t))^b$ where $f(t)$ is an infinitely differentiable function and b a constant number.

With the help of Wolfram, see many examples of derivatives, for example, for the eighth derivative
[image]

You can see in the picture that a certain pattern is met. The sum of the exponents of the different derivatives of $f(t)$ is equal to the value $i$ in each exponent of $(1 + f(t))^{b−i}$.
In addition, the sum of each exponent multiplied by the different derivatives of each f(t) is always equal to 8.

With this, I have a possible incomplete formula for the derived kth is:

$[(1+f(t))^{b}]^{(k)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}C(i,b) (1+f(t))^{b-i}(f^{(1)}(t))^{P_{i,1}}\cdots (f^{(k)}(t))^{P_{i,k}}$
where 
$P_{i,j}=0$ if $j>k,\quad \sum_{j=1}^{k}P_{i,j}=i$
and $\sum_{j=1}^{k}jP_{i,j}=k$, 
 $C(i,b)$ constants dependent of $i$ and $b$.

But it is incomplete, for example for $i = 3 $, there are four expressions of the form
 $(f^{(1)})(t))^{P_{3,1}}\cdots (f ^{(k)}(t))^{P_{3, k}}$
and in this way it should include a second sum, that is, something of the form 
 $\sum (f^{(1)}(t))^{P_{i, 1}}\cdots (f^{(k)}(t))^{P_{i, k}}$ but I can't see how it could be ...
Thanks in advance

actualization.

Now, i have this:

$[(1+f(t))^{b}]^{(k)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}C(i,b) (1+f(t))^{b-i}\sum_{j\in I_i} C(j)(f^{(1)}(t))^{P_{j,1}}\cdots (f^{(k)}(t))^{P_{j,k}}$
where 
$P_{j,l}=0$ if $l>k,\quad \sum_{l=1}^{k}P_{j,l}=i$
and $\sum_{l=1}^{k}lP_{j,l}=k$, 
 $C(i,b)$ constants dependent of $i$ and $b$.

and $I_i\subset \mathbb{N}$ is a finite set.
(this set would give the number of terms that appear next to each $(1+a(t))^{b-i})$
I would like to give more information about this set, but I can't do it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: thanks but I don't want to use that formula because information is lost in my opinion. For example, this formula does not tell me the pattern of the exponents as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton's generalized binomial theorem,
\begin{equation}
(1+f(t))^b = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(b)_k}{k!} f(t)^{k} .\hspace{1em} (1)
\end{equation}
Where $(b)_k = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(b-i)$. (When $b$ is a nonnegative integer, the binomial coefficients for $k > b$ are zero). 
And if you take derivatives both sides of (1),

$$[(1+f(t))^b]^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(b)_k}{k!} [f(t)^{k}]^{(n)} .$$
You can use Faá di Bruno's Formula to find the latter.

Comment: thanks But I'm looking for something like my post since after finding the formula I want to narrow the expression and get to that (with additional hypothesis for any $k, |f^{(k)}(t)|\leq|f(t)|)$\\ 
$|[(1+f(t))^b]^{(k)}|$
$ \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}|C(i,b)||(1+f(t))^{b−i}||f^{(1)}(t)^{P_{i,1}}|\cdots |f^{(k)}(t)^{P_{i,k}}|$
$\leq\sum_{i=1}^{k}|C(i,b)||(1+f(t))^{b}|(1+f(t))^{-i}|(1+f(t))^{i}|$
$=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|C(i,b)|(1+f(t))^b|$